# Is Beric Dondarrion a Targaryen?

Tags: character, game-of-thrones

Jaime Lannister said to Brienne:

> *When I was killing him, he had not expected to die.*

He said this when they were in the bath and he was talking about killing the Mad King.

It means (at least to me) that some Targaryens have the power to come back from death to life. I think Jon Snow came back to life by his family's power, not by the red woman's foolish prayer. If it is true, is Beric Dondarrion a Targaryen also? With consideration that Dondarrion is similar to Targaryen in pronunciation.

Comment: Welcome to Movies & TV! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [**How to Ask**](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @Paulie_D I edited that. Is it clear now?

Comment: Dondarrion = Targareyan because of pronuntition ?

Comment: Why it this protected? It has 3 downvotes and doesn't really help anything to do with movies.

Comment: @user00001 It was protected because it got 5 spam answers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the books, the name [Dondarrion](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Dondarrion) predates Aegon's conquest, so there is no relation to the Targaryen name and no evidence that Beric Dondarrion has Targaryen blood.

Jon Snow is the only Targaryen we have seen return from the dead. Every other Targaryen that has died has stayed dead. In fact, the two Targaryens to have died in the course of the show, Viserys and Maester Aemon, were never portrayed as returning from the dead. So I don't think there is any reason to believe that Targaryens have a power to return from the dead.

Also, what Jamie says is this:

> I don't think he expected to die. He meant to burn with the rest of us and rise again reborn as a dragon and turn his enemies to ash. I slit his throat to make sure that didn't happen.

Note that the Mad King (who was obviously mad) died and did not return from the dead either. So his belief in his ability to resurrect or in not being able to die was wrong, and can be explained by his madness.

Ultimately though, the show makes clear that Beric Dondarrion and Jon Snow both returned to life only through the intervention of the Lord of Light after the prayer of a Red Priest or Priestess, and not before. The show does not give us any reason to believe this is not the case. Indeed, while Thoros of Myr prays for Beric immediately upon his death, Jon Snow remains dead for quite a while until Melisandre's prayer.

And finally, while the show only mentions a few other Targaryens, the books mention many of them, and nowhere are any of them said to have cheated death.

So no, Beric Dondarrion's resurrection ability is not evidence of Targaryen blood.

Comment: Sorry for my bad question. I think return from dead is for black hair Targaryens. I must mentioned that in question. And if it is true returning from die, It has limit. for example 7 times. BTw Thanks for answer, And i am waiting for another answers to select the best one.

Comment: There is no evidence of a limit to resurrection. The only reason Beric hasn't been resurrected more is lack of opportunity. Jon Snow is the only black hair Targaryen. One person is hardly enough information to identify a trend. It seems you are intent on believing your theory regardless of evidence. In which case, I wish you well, but you won't find evidence to support it.

Comment: *It seems you are intent on believing your theory regardless of evidence.* No.. It is only a guess and i'm asking your opinion. My english is bad, but i am not fool.  :)

Comment: *lord of light :P

Comment: @ShubhamSinghrawat, maybe you said this *lord of light* because of my word *but i am not fool*. Maybe it has an arrogant meaning in english, but i don't meant that.  I mentioned **my english is not good**. I was trying to say believing a theory without evidence is foolish, and i do not decide to do this.

Comment: @FarzinKanzi my comment was in the reference to a typo in the answer. I wasn't referring to you my friend. Cheers =)

Comment: Thank you very much my friend, and sorry for my misunderstanding.

Comment: Occam's Razor would suggest the mad king's surprise at dying was more because he was insane, vs should have been immortal.